# python regex: extracting number from string, unknown number format

Tags: python, regex

I need to extract the first number from a string, but I don't know the exact format of the number.

The number could be one of the following formats...`1.224` some decimal... `3,455,000` some number with unknown number of commas... `45%` a percentage ... or just an integer `5`

it would be something like `blah blah $ 2,400` or `blah blah 45%` or `blah blah $1.23` or `blah blah 7`

would be interesting if it was intelligent enough to do word numbers too like `blah blah seven`

I don't need the dollar sign, just the number

Comment: What is "first number"(first digit or the entire number)? Should the commas or the decimals also be extracted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For extracting the first number from a string, with different formats, you could use `re.findall()`:

```
 import re

strings = ['45% blah 43%', '1.224 blah 3.2', '3,455,000 blah 4,3', '$1.2 blah blah $ 2,400', '3 blah blah 7']

for string in strings:
    first_match = re.findall(r'[0-9$,.%]+\d*', string)[0]
    print(first_match)
```

Which Outputs:

```
45%
1.224
3,455,000
$1.2
3
```

Comment: Can you please modify your answer to include the treatment of negative numbers?

Answer (score 2):

While this problem has many cases, here is a solution which solves most of them using some regex and the `re` module:

```
import re

def extractVal(s):
    return re.sub(r'^[^0-9$\-]*| .*$', '', s)
```

(1) It removes all leading string characters that are not 0-9, or $

(2) It removes all ending characters up to and including the first space (after (1))

Here's some data in action:

```
>>> data = ['blah $50,000 10', 'blah -1.224 blah', 'blah 3,455,000 blah', 'blah 45% 10 10 blah', '5 6 4']
>>> print(list(map(extractVal,data)))
['$50,000', '-1.224', '3,455,000', '45%', '5']
```

**This solution assumes that the first number ends in a space.**

We can go further as others have stated by converting these strings into numbers :

```
def valToInt(s):
    if '%' in s:
        a = float(s[:-1])/100
    else:
        a =  float(re.sub(r'[,$]','',s))
    return int(a) if a == int(a) else a
```

Resulting to (with the `map()` function again):

```
[50000, -1.224, 3455000, 0.45, 5]
```

Comment: One last thing... the text for percentage somtimes looks like this `blah blah 45 % blah` instead of `blah blah 45% blah` ...  with an extra space between the number and percentage sign... so it's giving me `45` instead of `45%`... is this easy to fix?

Comment: You could merely use `str.replace(' %','%')` at the very beginning

Comment: Oh... this might be tough... what about `blahh (2)% blah` for an output of `-0.02`?

Comment: Oh this also only works for positive numbers currently...  You could replace the parenthesis with an empty string

Comment: The solution has been updated to work with negative numbers.  You can remove parenthesis with `re.sub('\(|\)', '', s)`

Comment: If the only time parenthesis is used is with a percent you could simply replace`(` with `-`.  The more inconsistent the data is, the harder this problem is imo

Comment: Can you please modify the answer so I can find the `n` number?

Answer (score 1):

If you insist on a regex, then this should work (only limited to cases you mentioned):

```
rgx = re.compile(r'\d+(,|\.)?\d*')
assert rgx.search("blah blah $ 2,400")
assert rgx.search("blah blah 45%")
assert rgx.search("blah blah $1.23")
assert rgx.search("blah blah 7")
```

As for the `blah blah seven` I do not thing a regex would cut it (at least not for anything more complex than a single digit).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want an actual number, and that percents should be converted to a decimal:

```
str_ = "blah blah $ 2,400"
number, is_percent = re.search(r"([0-9,.]+)\s*(%?)", str_).groups() or (None, None)
if number is not None:
    number = float(number.replace(",", ""))
    if is_percent:
        number /= 100
```